# Web apps for managing financial portfolios

Tags: webapp-rec

I've been looking for a decent online portfolio manager for a while and not found anything. I'd like something that:

1. Is UK based, i.e. can price in GBP and can get UK fund prices
2. Can access a large range of funds, not just individual stocks
3. Automatically updates my fund/share prices
4. Is easy to enter transactions in bulk (not that I make that many, it's very, very off-putting entering all historical transactions one by one)
5. Has limited advertising

Google Spreadsheets has been the best I've found so far.

Comment: Would a broker like Etrade work?

Comment: @Shane, wont that only track trades completed through Etrade?  I'm looking to track funds with multiple providers, e.g. pension funds, funds bought through a fund supermarket as well as a few individual company shares.

Answer (score 2):

No idea about support for UK funds, but Mint.com is a decent financial app.  It may not give you the level of detail you're looking for, but it does keep track of individual account balances & transactions.  I use it to track my retirement accounts & bank accounts, but I haven't tried plugging any individual stocks into it.

Comment: I've looked into Mint.com previously but it's heavily US focussed.  It's just the kind of app I'm looking for if only there was a UK-centric version

Answer (score 0):

Find a broker software that works for you and you should be able to use all the tools with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Strands Money](http://money.strands.com)

Answer (score 0):

Hava you tried [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/)? I found it pretty useful, but I don't know about UK and GBP features.

Answer (score -1):

MoneyDashboard should have good UK support:

[image: MoneyDashboard]
<sub>(source: [moneydashboard.com](https://www.moneydashboard.com/images/footerLogo.png))</sub>